# Making a toast in android call a variable from a different method

Tags: java, android, google-maps

For a project I'm working on, I want to find the distance between the user and another marker. Bellow, the 'distance' method uses the haversin formula to find the distance between twos sets of latitudes and longitudes. I also have a toast written (which isn't working) to try and say something like "You are 'x' away from the marker". Anyone know the best way to change my toast so that it will print out this?

In short, how do I modify where I implemented my toast, to call my distance() method and print the distance in the toast

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    Double distance;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Double distance = 1.0;
                int val = 1;

//This is where I put 4 different lat and longs to find distace between all
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), distance(1.3, -1.34, 13.4,-23, "K"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "vlaue is "+val, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return "Text from Function";
    }

    private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == "K") {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
        } else if (unit == "N") {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }

        return (dist);
    }
    private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
    }


}
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working?  Does the code not compile?  Or does it not run?

Comment: @EJK no it's not running, theres an error in the lines where I initalise my toast. I think I didn't acutlly use the toast function correctly. I just don't know exactly what I did wrong

Comment: Yes, but what type of error?  Compilation error or runtime error?

Comment: Please post the text of the error. If it is runtime, is there a stack trace?

Comment: @EJK It says that it couldnt resolve method 'makeText' as I have the wrong parameters in, it says that it needs, android.contentContent, double, int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, as it needs to be a string, not a double.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(distance(1.3, -1.34, 13.4,-23, "K")), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
```

Comment: Thanks that did exactly what I wanted it to :)